# MySQL: "Too many connections"?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error:

> **Warning:** mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Too many
>   connections in **/home1/host/public_html/employee/message/config.php**
>   on line **4**
>
> **Could no connect to database. Too many connections**

No one else is on my site at the moment. I'm the only one.

I do have a lot of AJAX, but the connections close after they're done. That is why I don't understand why I have a `too many connections` error.

Comment: do a `show processlist;` in mysql, to see the active connections.

Comment: Do you know what the connection limit for the server is?

Comment: If it is not other users flooding the MySQL server, the first thing that comes to my mind is that the files is being included more than once.

Comment: @AdamWenger - Nope. I forgot to mention I'm on shared hosting. Could that maybe be the problem? But I'm pretty sure the connection limit is for each account, not the whole server. Where is the connection limit set at so I can see it? The php.ini file? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @Nican - I only have it included once. Actually, I am using require_once() and I only have it on the page once. (at the top) I am on shared hosting but this neve happened before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to see if connection closes properly after your do AJAX request by querying your MYSQL?

Comment: Here's the only thing that worked in our case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226015/error-too-many-connections-on-codeigniter-website

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a webserver (IIS, Apache, etc)?  They often pool the connections and hang on to them for a while to keep queries running fast.  If you are, try restarting your webserver app (in IIS, Start -> Run "iisreset") and see if that frees it up.

Comment: I wish I could do that. But I don't have my own server, I'm on a host. It is an Apache web server.

Comment: I wonder if I should manually close the connections with `mysql_close()`?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to Multiple connection instance are active at a time.
Use Singleton object for Connection object creation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close all existing database connections before making another connection. Do this by using the code `$mysqlConnectionName->close();` or `mysql_close($mysqlConnectionName);`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a custom framework that I am using. The solution was to create one connection per http request (new mysqli).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31766451)